# Proof for diametral plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, solid-geometry

I have seen a statement in a text book which is given as a passing reference. It says that diametral plane of surface $f(x,y,z) = 0$ is given as $l\frac{df}{dx}+m\frac{df}{dy}+n\frac{df}{dz} = 0 $  in direction of $l,m,n$ - system of parallel chords.

Given a conicoid - $ax^2+by^2+cz^2 = 0 $ and system of parallel chords in direction $l,m,n$ I can derive diametral plane as $alx+bmy+cnz = 0 $ by taking the mid-point and general equation of the line and making sum of roots $= 0$.

But how to prove diametral equation form (1) ...Any idea Pls?

Comment: Where are these derivatives evaluated?

Comment: Sir it just says - equation of diametral plane is given by (1). Nothing much given. Usually i know that for surface f, $\nabla f$ is normal. But i am thinking how normal is perpendicular to l,m,n

Comment: Without knowing where this gradient is supposed to be evaluated, this equation is virtually devoid of content. I should think that there’s *some* context for in in the text.

Comment: that is on surface f(x,y,z) = 0

Comment: That’s a lot of points. This equation also has no variables. Presumably, $(l,m,n)$ is a fixed direction vector, so where are the $x$, $y$ and $z$ that would make this an implicit equation of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$? Perhaps you should include more of the context from this text.

Comment: Sir take chords in direction of l,m,n, Take midpoints of these chords - $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ Diametral plane is locus of these $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$.So derivative should be at these mid points $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$. Locus of $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ will be x,y,z equation

Comment: Nothing much written in textbook actually. I am thinking in these lines

Comment: @amd <ax, by, zn> are direction ratio's of normal at (x,y,z) point. l,m,n are direction cosines of system of parallel chords. How can they be perpendicular? this is what i am thinking.

Comment: You can find a proof of that formula here: http://www.solitaryroad.com/c403.html